# C# inheritance - arrays invalid, lists valid?

Tags: c#, inheritance

This is a newbie question. Why can't I inherit from an array, similar to how I inherit from a list?

For example:

```js
public class Foo
{}

public class FoosArray : Foo[] // invalid "unexpected token" error message
{}

public class FoosList : List<Foo> // valid
{}
```

Comment: `List<T>` is a class. `Foo[]` is not a class.

Comment: @JohnSaunders That depends on how you define "class". It is a reference type which is not an interface. But I think I know what you mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Arrays` are special types. The implementation of arrays is provided by CLR at runtime. Array is the base class for all array types, but there is no class such as `Foo[]` so you can't inherit from it since there is no implementation.

Comment: Also, `Foo[]`, while being a special type, can be considered a `sealed` type. If I remember correctly, `typeof(Foo[]).IsSealed` returns `true`.

Comment: I noticed both: it is sealed and also not a class in the sense that it can't be inherited from. This answers my question.